# Imagemagick diagonal linear gradient with multiple stops using custom svg

Tags: svg, imagemagick, gradient

I'm trying to create a diagonal linear gradient background using a custom svg, but ImageMagick doesnt recognize the gradient path specified on the svg. The gradient should start at top left corner and end in bottom right corner.

**First approach**
I've tried using `$imagick->newPseudoImage(600, 600, 'gradient:startColor-endColor')` but it does not support multiple stops in the gradient. It does however support diagonal using `$imagick->setOption('vector', '0,0,600,600')` - topleft to bottomright

**Second approach**
Second approach was to create an inline svg (with gradient specified) and feed that to Imagick, but the svg parser doesn't recognize the diagonal path specified and default to either vertical og horizontial gradient. It does however support multiple color stops (offsets). Below is the used svg along with the resulting image.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="600px" height="600px" >
    <defs>
         <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="100%">
               <stop offset="0%" stop-color="black"/>
               <stop offset="50%" stop-color="red"/>
               <stop offset="100%" stop-color="orange"/>
         </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#gradient)"/>
</svg>
```

```
$image = new Imagick();
$image->readImageBlob($svg);
$image->setImageFormat("svg");
```

[image]

I actually really like the idea of feeding an svg to Imagick, but i'm not sure how to fix this issue.

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Does it support a gradientTransform in the second approach? If not what does it mean that the "svg parser doesn't recognize the diagonal path specified"

Comment: In the second approach the gradient path (vector) is (0,0) -> (600,600), but the gradient is drawn from (0,0) -> (0, 600)

Comment: And with a gradientTransform?

Comment: You may try this: `<linearGradient id="gradient" gradientTransform = "rotate(30 .5 .5)">` Please read more about gradientTransform

Comment: I cant make it work with gradientTransform

Comment: I found a solution and I've updated the question

Comment: What is the SVG renderer you are using in Imagemagick? Is it the Imagemagick internal MSVG/XML or RSVG delegate or Inkscape. Try installing Inkscape and Imagemagick will use it automatically. It is the best SVG renderer. The internal Imagemagick renderer is rather simplistic.

Comment: If you want a raster gradient, you can try my multigradient script if on a Unix-like system. See my web site at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for me was to install inkscape using

```
brew install inkscape
```

ImageMagick will attempt to use inkscape or RSVG if found in your path. Otherwise, it will default to it's own internal svg renderer.